# In SwiftUI, the ternary operator is ignored for animation duration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, swiftui

This is the code of my app:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var animationAmount: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var animate: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        Button("Tap Mee") {
            animate = !animate
            // self.animationAmount += 1
            print("yo, animate is", animate)
        }
        .padding(40)
        .background(Color.red)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(
            Circle()
                .stroke(Color.red)
                .scaleEffect(animationAmount)
                .opacity(Double(2 - animationAmount))
                .animation(
                    
                    Animation.easeOut(duration: animate ? 5 : 1)
                        .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
                    
                )
        )
        .onAppear {
            self.animationAmount = 2
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set animation to 1 or 5 depending on the click. On the click a property is changed (true or false) and I want to use that to control the duration, but it is ignored. How can I fix this, so on each click, the duration of the animation changes?

Comment: Just a bit of syntactic sugar... `animate = !animate` can be done like... `animate.toggle()` :D

Comment: `.repeatForever` tells the animation to, well, repeat forever *with those parameters*. You'll need to stop that animation and restart a new animation with the new duration.